# Django Forms Invalid but no Errors

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Maybe it might be an oversight but I do not know the point where I am getting it wrong.
My form is rendered correctly but it keeps failing without errors.

**forms.py**

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class BeneficiaryForm(forms.Form):
    """Add Beneficiary template form"""
    # Form fields
    account_currency = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Currency.objects.all(), empty_label=_('Select account currency'))
    bank_account_type = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=False, help_text=_("We'll notify them when a transfer is made"))
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    swift_code = forms.CharField(max_length=11, required=False,
                                 widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'MSBCCNBJ001'}))
    iban = forms.CharField(max_length=34)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BeneficiaryForm, self).__init__()
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

**views.py**

```
def beneficiaries(request):
    """View function for viewing Beneficiaries and adding a Beneficiary instance"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BeneficiaryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid")
            print(request.POST['bank_account_type'])
            print(request.POST['email'])
            print(request.POST['name'])
            print(request.POST['iban'])
            print(request.POST['swift_code'])

        print("Form is invalid")
        print(form.errors)
    form = BeneficiaryForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/beneficiaries.html', context)
```

and in my rendered form. I have this block to show errors and nothing shows up

**HTML**

```
<form action="{% url 'beneficiary_index' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {% if field != '__all__' %}
        <strong>{{ field.label }}:</strong>
        {% endif %}
        {{ error|escape}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="default-01">{% trans "Account currency" %}</label>'
        </div>
        {{ form.account_currency | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="default-01">{% trans "Bank Account type" %}</label>
        </div>
        {{ form.bank_account_type | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="default-01">Their email(optional)</label>
        </div>
        {{ form.email | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="default-01">Full name of account holder</label>
        </div>
        {{ form.name | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <h6>{% trans "Recipient Bank Information" %}</h6>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="default-01">Swift code</label>
        </div>
        {{ form.swift_code | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="default-01">IBAN</label>
        </div>
        {{ form.iban | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">{% trans 'Add Beneficiary' %}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the Html to the form. I have just tried all the suggestions and still without the errors.
Form is Invalid is the only thing printed on screen without the `form.errors`

Comment: `it keeps failing without errors.` - you are getting 'Form is invalid' printed but no errors? You are re-creating the form outside your POST block and not returning anything in the POST block

Comment: Why did you put `__init__` method outside of `BeneficiaryForm` ?

Comment: @Subham he probably just formatted it incorrectly in his question

Comment: Show your `html` with the form in it please

Comment: I have added the html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `GET` request empty form in the `else` block or return the request in the `POST` block.

You are re-creating an empty form before returning the response.

```
def beneficiaries(request):
    """View function for viewing Beneficiaries and adding a Beneficiary instance"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BeneficiaryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid")
            print(request.POST['bank_account_type'])
            print(request.POST['email'])
            print(request.POST['name'])
            print(request.POST['iban'])
            print(request.POST['swift_code'])
            # do other stuff like saving to DB
            # then redirect 
        else:
            print("Form is invalid")
            print(form.errors)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = BeneficiaryForm()
    else:
        # maybe return 404
        pass
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/beneficiaries.html', context)
```

Or maybe you can try [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/), to avoid the `if-else` block for `GET` and `POST` requests.

Comment: I still get Form is invalid printed but without errors https://prnt.sc/wp1nvn

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the place you want the error to appear (In the HTML file)

Better if you use it inside the  tags.

```
{% if form.errors %}
   <p>Form is invalid</p>
{% endif %}
```

I Hope this answers the question.

Comment: I have added the html. You can see i checked errors to be displayed

Comment: Yes. Do you want to display the exact error? If not, remove   {% for field in form %} {% for error in field.errors %} tags. Then display a custom error message by using HTML tags. (example - <p>Form is invalid</p> ) between the {% if form.errors %} tag